# Erro na conexao Android com Web Service Restfull

Tags: java, android, web-service, post

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo android para uma disciplina na faculdade. Estou conectando o Web Service Restfull com o android utilizando a biblioteca Gson para passar dados.

No método abaixo estou realizando uma requisição POST, no que realizo esse conexão via web ela funciona normal, entretanto nesse método ele está apresentando o erro 500 na conexão.

```
public class CadastrarMarca extends AppCompatActivity {

HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
EditText editTextMarcaCadastro;
Button buttonSalvarMarca;
Marca marca = new Marca();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastrar_marca);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    editTextMarcaCadastro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMarcaCadastro);
    buttonSalvarMarca = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSalvarMarca);
    buttonSalvarMarca.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            marca.setNome(editTextMarcaCadastro.getText().toString());
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.73.110:8080/MrBar/rest/marca");
                        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
                        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                        urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
                        urlConnection.connect();
                        System.out.println(urlConnection.getResponseCode() + " Mensagem de sucesso ou falaha na conexao");
                        OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
                        OutputStreamWriter streamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");


                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        String jsonMarca = gson.toJson(marca);
                        streamWriter.write(jsonMarca);
                        streamWriter.flush();
                        streamWriter.close();
                        outputStream.close();
                        urlConnection.disconnect();*/
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Agradeço desde já.

Segue o erro abaixo

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [br.com.mrbar.util.MrBarResourcesConfig] in context with path [/MrBar] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to create saveOrUpdate event with null entity] with root cause
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to create saveOrUpdate event with null entity

Comment: Poderia adicionar a mensagem de erro? Isso deve ajudar a detectar o problema real. 500 é o código HTTP genérico para erros do lado do servidor.

Comment: Eu adicionarei sim, no android Studio exibe apenas a mensagem 500, vou colocar o erro que vem no console do Web-Service.

Comment: Aparentemente o erro está no lado servidor e não na aplicação.

Comment: Aparentemente pelo que notei o objeto não está sendo gravado por estar null, ou seja, ele não está sendo passado de forma correta, creio eu.

Comment: Alguém?????????

Answer (score 2):

Faça o download de uma ferramenta chamada POSTMAN (https://www.getpostman.com) e simule a chamada usando o método, dados e parametros que vc está utilizando no seu código java.

Se vc obter a resposta correta no POSTMAN, o backend está funcionando como deveria e o problema está no seu código.

O erro que vc enviou aparenta ser que o backend (servlet) não recebeu os dados(null) e disparou um IllegalArgumentException.

Posso estar errado (não programo em java há mais de 15 anos), mas olhando o seu código eu diria que vc tem ter o dados prontos para serem enviados antes do Connect(), pois quando vc conecta no webserver, todos os requisitos necessarios para processar o request devem estar disponiveis, e aparentement no seu código estão vindo depois e disparando a IllegalArgumentException no servidor.

Faça o teste.

Answer (score 0):

Marcos, você está utilizando hibernate para persistir seu objeto na base correto?

Ao salvar a entidade (Persistir), ela está indo nula, retornando a exceção.

Caso nao seja esse o problema, posta o código do seu service/dao para verificarmos o que pode ser o causador da exceção.